# Postgres vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Can anyone share proper advantages-disadvantages? If possible, I am trying to search for really great benchmarks between both, so please share it with me.

Also, which will be best between them for Transacts(I know SQL server is specially made for T-SQL, but even if you choose Postgres over SQL Server, then why?)? I am trying to experiment.

Comment: See [here](http://datachomp.com/archives/top-10-reasons-i-like-postgres-over-sql-server/) and [here](https://www.pg-versus-ms.com/) and [here](http://facility9.com/2011/12/ten-reasons-postgresql-is-better-than-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3):

[Bent Ozar](https://stackexchange.com/users/13381/brent-ozar) has a good article about why [benchmarking is rarely seen](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/05/the-dewitt-clause-why-you-rarely-see-database-benchmarks/) based on [Dr. David DeWitt](https://www.linkedin.com/in/david-dewitt-30189b50/).

> BENCHMARK TESTING. You must obtain Microsoft’s prior written approval
>   to disclose to a third party the results of any benchmark test of the
>   software.

But, one is free and one isn't so there is a big difference to consider among the laundry list of others (IDE, HA/DR, Auditing, Server operating systems, Supported laguages, etc).

There are also some older posts on Stackoverflow comparing the two, with many folks providing their opinions.

- [GIS: PostGIS/PostgreSQL vs. MySql vs. SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=postgresql%20vs%20sql%20server)
- [DB2 vs PostgreSQL vs SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371560/db2-vs-postgresql-vs-sql-server)
- [Brent Ozar: Two Important Differences Between SQL Server & PostgreSQL](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/08/two-important-differences-between-sql-server-and-postgresql/)

Dr. Dewitt also has a great video about [query optimization.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/06/video-sql-query-optimization-why-is-it-so-hard-to-get-right/) which is slightly relevant but more so just a great watch.